# eclipse website security certificate

Tags: eclipse, ssl, certificate, sslhandshakeexception, http-unit

I am working on httpunit in eclipse.I am accessing a website,through WebConversation class of httpunit.This website uses https protocol.Hence I am getting the below exception when i am trying to run my java program.

Exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

I have downloaded the certificate's certificate in my local machine.How to import it in eclipse?
Thanks